# Multer with Internal Server Error 500 on Cpanel

Tags: node.js, cpanel, multer

I'm currently building an Nodejs API on Cpanel so my front end can send the image using post API and Nodejs will use Multer to save the received files to the server in Public_html folder so I can access it from front-end

But the current issue is that, once I send files to API, it always return error 500 and no request was being processed. This works fine on my dev env but once I deploy it to Prod/ on Cpanel, it stopped working.

Here is my server code, I'm currently using POSTMAN to test it.

```
// image storage location
const multerPath = path.join(__dirname, '../', 'public_html', 'source_img123/');

// multer storage configuration
const imageStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, multerPath);
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
  },
});


const upload = multer({storage: imageStorage});
    
app.post('/api/upload', upload.array('files'), (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.files)
});
```

In Postman, I'm sure I'm using formdata and "files" name matches upload "files" name, and I have one more key called ID with text.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you confirmed that postman is actually sending the files as expected? I have had issues in the past using postman for file upload testing

Comment: Are you sure you have access there to save files in the indicated folder? Did you try to intercept unhandled errors and return the error with stacktrace as a 500 error response?

Comment: I'm sure, because if there is no file, the server will response with request body. Once I send file in the server return error 500. @d0rf47

Comment: @Anatoly, That's one of the issue I'm facing, Cpanel is not giving me any error and I can't troubleshoot it.

Comment: what do you see if you console.log req.body & req.files? Also you probably dont see any errors cause there is no error handling in the code.

Comment: @d0rf47, There is no error handling is because in Cpanel, we can't see any console log error and only error will be showing in a error log file but I don't see any in there when I throw error.